# Creating Layered Custom Control Templates (WPF 4 / .net 4.0 / C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, styling, controltemplate

I need some help in trying to recreate the following style:

[image: My Custom Style]

The ***sea of red can be ignored*** because it's just the background the textbox is sitting on.

To create the textbox I use the following xaml:

```
            <TextBox Name="tbSorageName"
                     Grid.Column="1"
                     Width="250"
                     Height="30"
                     Margin="0"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                     VerticalAlignment="Top"
                     IsReadOnly="True"
                     Style="{StaticResource MainTextBoxStyle}"
                     Text="{Binding SelectedStorage.Name,
                                    Mode=OneWay,
                                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

To style it, I used the following style:

```
<Style x:Key="MainTextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Snow" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri" />
    <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource MainTextBox_BGBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource MainTextBox_BorderBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
    <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Left" />
</Style>
```

The Brushes I use are:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MainTextBox_BGBrush" Color="#3A3A3A" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MainTextBox_BorderBrush" Color="#656565" />
```

That creates the basic textbox I use in my application, but I want to take my design much further by floating some meaningful text that describes the contents of textbox on the right hand side of the text box - So it should be anchored to the right hand side.

Comment: Forge an example of what you want it to look like could help.

Comment: There should be a small image/pic I made in paint.net at the top of my quesiton that illustrates what I am trying to do. Can you not see it?

Comment: Sorry, I thought that what is viewed you already got and you want to further improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily via 2 approaches.

1.Create a user control that consists of a textbox and a textblock.  The Xaml for the UserControl would look similar to the following

```
<Grid Width="{Binding Path=Width, ElementName=tbSorageName}" Height="{Binding Path=Height, ElementName=tbSorageName}">
   <TextBox Name="tbSorageName"
                 Grid.Column="1"
                 Width="250"
                 Height="30"
                 Margin="0"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top"
                 IsReadOnly="True"
                 Style="{StaticResource MainTextBoxStyle}"
                 Text="hello" />
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5" Foreground="Red" FontStyle="Italic">Name</TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

2.Overlay an [Adorner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737.aspx) on the textbox and draw the description over the Textbox yourself via an OnRender Override.

I would go with the Usercontrol approach since that is cleaner and easier to maintain.

Comment: What about a custom control template?

Comment: That works too, though it seems a bit too heavy handed for something so simple.

Comment: OK - my only question that remains is how would you feed information into individual controls that wrapped by a custom control? i.e how would set the text of the second textbox when instantiating the custom control in .xaml?

Comment: Oh that's easy, create a Dependency Property for the label in your Custom/User Control.  Bind to this Property in your Xaml as your label text.  Then when you set/bind the Dependency Property on your User Control, your label will change.

Comment: TY so much you have answered my question more than I was expecting. When I start working on this.